# Eliminar parte de uma string e manter URL contida nela

Tags: php, javascript, string, url

Dentro de uma string há um trecho utilizado pelo Wordpress para exibir a imagem em meio à uma notícia, é possível eu remover todo esse trecho da string e aproveitar a URL da imagem?

```
$conteudonoticia = '[caption id="attachment_42478" align="alignleft" width="640"] <img class="wp-image-42478 size-full" src="http://paginalocal/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/20140815_174009.jpg" alt="20140815_174009" width="640" height="480" />Objetivo com a antecipação é garantir comodidade e tranquilidade aos servidores para as festas de final de ano[/caption]'
```

Elminiar todo o resto.

```
$urlimagem = 'http://paginalocal/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/20140815_174009.jpg'
```

Comment: veja se atende  https://ideone.com/RVzHzC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Leonardo Rafael Villas Bôas você pode utilizar expressões regulares (regex).

segue exemplo: [Pegar apenas a URL](https://regex101.com/r/kyCZgh/4)

Em PHP ficaria assim:

```
$conteudonoticia = '[caption id="attachment_42478" align="alignleft" width="640"] <img class="wp-image-42478 size-full" src="http://paginalocal/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/20140815_174009.jpg" alt="20140815_174009" width="640" height="480" />Objetivo com a antecipação é garantir comodidade e tranquilidade aos servidores para as festas de final de ano[/caption][caption id="attachment_42478" align="alignleft" width="640"] <img class="wp-image-42478 size-full" src="http://paginalocal/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/20140815_174010.jpeg" alt="20140815_174009" width="640" height="480" />Objetivo com a antecipação é garantir comodidade e tranquilidade aos servidores para as festas de final de ano[/caption][caption id="attachment_42478" align="alignleft" width="640"] <img class="wp-image-42478 size-full" src="http://paginalocal/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/20140815_174011.png" alt="20140815_174009" width="640" height="480" />Objetivo com a antecipação é garantir comodidade e tranquilidade aos servidores para as festas de final de ano[/caption]';

$regex = '~(\[caption.*?\]).*?(http.*?\.[a-z]{3,4}).*?(\[\/caption\])~';

preg_match_all($regex, $conteudonoticia, $matches);
array_shift($matches);

$resul = [];
for ($aux = 0; $aux < count($matches); $aux++) {
    array_push($resul, implode(" ", array_column($matches, $aux)));
}

print_r($resul);

/* Resultado
Array
(
    [0] => [caption id="attachment_42478" align="alignleft" width="640"] http://paginalocal/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/20140815_174009.jpg [/caption]
    [1] => [caption id="attachment_42478" align="alignleft" width="640"] http://paginalocal/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/20140815_174010.jpeg [/caption]
    [2] => [caption id="attachment_42478" align="alignleft" width="640"] http://paginalocal/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/20140815_174011.png [/caption]
)
*/
```

Obs.: Fiz a regex para aceitar os principais formatos de imagens: `.jpg, .png ou .jpeg`. Qualquer dúvida só perguntar.

Comment: Funcionou legal, mas como havia mais de uma imagem ele pegou a url de todas que estavam presentes. Seria necessário também apagar o trecho [caption] .... [/caption] do conteúdo principal.

Comment: Alterei o comentário para atender a ideia que passou agora.

Comment: Resolvido. Muito obrigado Djalma! :D

Answer (score 0):

Fiz 2 exemplos funcionais, utilize o que você achar melhor, deve existir outras formas só que fiz apenas essas.

```js
var conteudo = '[caption id="attachment_42478" align="alignleft" width="640"] <img class="wp-image-42478 size-full" src="http://paginalocal/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/20140815_174009.jpg" alt="20140815_174009" width="640" height="480" />Objetivo com a antecipação é garantir comodidade e tranquilidade aos servidores para as festas de final de ano[/caption]';

alert(conteudo.split('src=')[1].split('"')[1]);
    

alert(jQuery('<div '+conteudo+'>').attr('src'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[**exemplo com 1 url - ideone**](https://ideone.com/RVzHzC)

[**exemplo com 3 urls - ideone**](https://ideone.com/kt7BX0)

Com o uso de regex

```
$conteudonoticia = '[caption id="attachment_42478" align="alignleft" width="640"] <img class="wp-image-42478 size-full" src="http://paginalocal/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/20140815_174009.jpg" alt="20140815_174009" width="640" height="480" />Objetivo com a antecipação é garantir comodidade e tranquilidade aos servidores para as festas de final de ano[/caption]';

preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $conteudonoticia, $match);

print_r($match[0]);
```

Se desejar saída em forma de string substitua  `print_r($match[0]);` por

```
 $url = (implode(':', $match[0]));
 echo $url;
```

[**exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/kTUiXX)

**Documentação**

- [Expressões regulares](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)
- [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)